# Texture got dark gradient at one edge

Tags: texturing, uv

I just started blender this month. When I put texture to my objects, they got some weird dark gradient. Btw I tried to recalculate normal, apply transformation. Nothing's worked. Here's the screenshot in render mode.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it an image texture? Can you show the texture / nodes? Could be a color space / gamma problem?

Comment: I use standard principled bsdf setup. Picture is attached above.

Comment: Looks OK.. some misinterpretation of the images? Color space in the color component?  Height-map / Normal map muddle?  Someone who knows better may come along ..

Comment: Looks like you are using a texture which is *not* tileable @Andreasm

Comment: @brockmann it's working fine on other models.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by using smooth shading on an object with sharp corners. Blender is trying to make a 90 degree corner look like it's smooth. This leads to various shading issues as seen in the image. Setting the shading to flat is the best solution, but using split normals, an *Edge Split* modifier, or using the *Auto Smooth* normals option all work too.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution. I just have to split the normal. Still, I have no idea what is the actual problem.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to split the normals, if you are not forced to. See Brenticus answer above. The best is to use "Normals>Auto Smooth" and set an angle or set your mesh to flat shaded.

[image]